# How to find length of vector in a particular direction?

Tags: vectors

How do you solve this:

[image]

How do I find how long the red line is?

Answer (score 0):

you can find the angle $t$ between your $m$ and the unit vector $d.$ it is given by $\cos t = \dfrac{m.t}{|m|}$ the component in the direction orthogonal has length $|m|\sin t.$

Answer (score 0):

assuming vector $\vec{d}$ and $\vec{q}$ have unite length.

$\vec{m}_q$ is projection of $\vec{m}$ on $\vec{q}$:

$$\vec{m}_q=(\vec{m}\cdot \vec{q})\vec{q}$$
$$|\vec{red}|=|\vec{m}-(\vec{m}\cdot \vec{q})\vec{q}|$$

Comment: So q is perp to d?

Comment: @Murplyx sorry for late. yes. I called the other blue vector as $q$.